# Elasticsearch: Boost just one document

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine I have a number of documents in an Elasticsearch index:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Apple",
        "special": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "Orange",
        "special": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Pear",
        "special": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Raspberry",
        "special": 3
    },
    {
        "name": "Strawberry",
        "special": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "Mango",
        "special": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "Blackberry",
        "special": 3
    }
]
```

I want to get 3 of these at random.

But here's the tricky part: I also want to 'reserve' one of those 3 result 'slots' for a document with `special` greater than `0`.

If there aren't any, the slot can be given to any document, but if there are one or more documents which meet that requirement, just one of them should take that 'slot'.

But I'm not sure how to do that.

I see that there are ways to adjust the `score` of each result based on an evaluation of the document, such as the `script_score` function.

However, in order to only boost *just one* valid document, presumably I'd need some way to maintain a state recording whether a valid document has been boosted or not.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at the [`pinned` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-pinned-query.html)

Comment: Interesting, although unfortunately I don't know the IDs ahead of time.

Comment: I am looking to solve a similar problem at the moment.  The only solution I've been able to come up with is to perform two searches in parallel using the _msearch endpoint: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html

One search for a random document where special > 0 and one search for 2 documents where special = 0.  Then I would have the client combine the results.  Let me know if you came up with a solution to do this with only 1 search.